# HTTP 401 Unauthorized error using web service from .NET 4, ok from .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I've got a web service, and C# code generated by WSDL.exe for accessing it. Using this with the code below from a .NET 3.5 project works ok, but if I change the project to target .NET 4.0 then it fails with an HTTP 401 Unauthorized error. I don't know what has changed between version 3.5 and 4.0 of .NET that would cause this problem? Any help is much appreciated!

```
var service = new MyService(); //MyService class generated by WSDL.exe
service.Url = "https://mymachine:8443/ServiceBean";
service.PreAuthenticate = true;
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
service.MyMethod();
```

Comment: Maybe try running fiddler and see how the calls differ in the different versions?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, I did try that but couldn't see the difference.

Comment: I think it's to do with NTLM authentication changes, but don't know if I can make .NET 4.0 have the same behaviour for this as .NET 3.5.